# Can't use Wget in VSCode due to Invalid Syntax Error Message

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i'm trying to use the following code, but it continues to show me invalid syntax.

```
!wget -O file_name.csv https://website.com/file_name.csv
```

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If that's supposed to be Python, it's not anything close.

Comment: Is this in a Jupyter Notebook context? If so, you've left out some key details from your question and its tags.

Answer (score 0):

That "!" syntax is a feature of Jupyter.  It's not part of Python, and it's not part of VSCode.  You can use the terminal window in VSCode to enter your `wget` command (without the "!").

Answer (score -2):

Ensure you use the correct shell firstly.

And delete the "!" before wget. I can't understand why "!" was added before the wget command.

Comment: He is using VSCode, and why should the operating system matter?

Comment: @Tim Roberts Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly. I mean that according to his description, he  use vscode on Linux